Ringel's interpretation of quantum groups as Hall algebras at $q=1$
Let $Q$ be a finite-type quiver and let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the semisimple Lie algebra associated with the corresponding simply-laced Dynkin diagram. Let $U_v^+(\mathfrak{g})$ be the positive part of the corresponding quantum group.
Ringel gave a very nice interpretation of the specialization of $U_v^+(\mathfrak{g})$ at $v=q^\frac{1}{2}$ for $q$ a prime power as the Hall algebra for the category of representations of $Q$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. I am wondering whether there is a similar story for the specialization at $v=1$, which is simply the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{n})$ of the positive part of $\mathfrak{g}$. Can $U(\mathfrak{n})$ be realized as the Hall algebra for a category of "representations of $Q$ over $\mathbb{F}_1$"?
A tentative definition for what "representation of $Q$ over $\mathbb{F}_1$" might mean is a diagram of shape $Q$ in the category of finite sets and partial bijections (i.e. a morphism from $X$ to $Y$ is a bijection from a subset of $X$ to a subset of $Y$). This has the right number of isomorphism classes of objects of each dimension vector (i.e. Kostant partition function many) in type $A$, but not in other types (for example, there is no indecomposable object with dimension vector given by the highest root in type $D_4$). I'd be interested to know if this does give the right answer in type $A$ and whether it can be fixed in types $D$ and $E$.

It has been quite some time since I last looked at this paper, but it contains almost all of your observations (including the counterexample in type D4), and confirms the isomorphism in type A. I don't know if there has been any follow up since then. https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0912
